# Child elements outside parent div

Tags: html, css

It appears that **all the elements nested inside my parent divs are overflowing** from the bottom border of my parental divs.

As you can see the image divs overlay the parent and the paragraph on the header

Similar questions have to deal with floating elements, but this is not the applicable here since I don't use those

Why is "position:relative" ?

Here is the code,
and a ready fiddle for your, very much appreciated ,tweaks.

https://jsfiddle.net/r96fxfgj/

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <title>DISSECTIONS</title>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dissections.css">
    </head>
        <body>
            <div id="header">
                <p><span>/<sup>*</sup></span>DISSECTIONS</p>
            </div>
            <div id="main">
                <div class="photo" id="one"> </div>
                <div class="photo" id="two"> </div>
                <div class="photo" id="three"> </div>
                <div class="photo" id="four"> </div>
                <span class="stretch"></span>
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                <button id="about"> ABOUT </button>
                <button id="contact"> CONTACT </button>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```
    body {
        overflow: hidden; /*prevents scrolling*/
        font-family: courier;
    }
    
    div {
        width: 98vw;
    
    }
    
    p{
        font-size: 8vh;
    
    }
    span {
        font-size: 15vh;
    }
    sup {
        font-size: 8vh;
    }
    
            
    #header {
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 20vh;
        padding: 0;
    }
    
    
    #main {
        border: 2px solid red;
        height: 60vh;
        margin-top: 5vh;
        margin-bottom: 5vh;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: justify; /*justify*/
    }
    .stretch { /*justify*/
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    
    .photo {
        border: 2px solid black;
        height: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 20vw;
        margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-image: url(
            http://www.publicdomainpictures.net/pictures/10000/nahled/1001-12380278201dXT.jpg);
    }
    
    #footer {
        border: 2px solid blue;
        height: 10vh;
        bottom: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few separate but similar issues here.  Most boil down to you're unintentionally setting a specific height for the parent which is smaller than the things it contains.

In general it's best to set specific heights or widths only when your design actually needs those specific sizes -- otherwise just let the content flow dictate the size of its parents.

- text in header overflowing the container:   Fonts are a bit weird when it comes to sizing -- the value you put in `font-size` will match the text itself, but will also scale the padding above and below the text to a (typically) larger value (this is in addition to the normal `padding` attribute found on other elements).  You can fix this by setting values for the text's `line-height` (a cheap but often-used hack for short headers is `line-height:1px`, which will remove all the extra padding.  Don't use this if there's any chance the text will wrap to a second line, though, or the second line will overlap the first.)
- images overflowing `#main`:  you're setting #main as a percentage of the viewport height, but images at 100% of their actual size -- so depending on the window size the images may end up larger than or smaller than the container.  Either use the same units for both, or don't set a height on #main at all (therefore letting the images dictate the height of the container.)
- `position:relative` -- I don't see this in your code but I've seen it confuse a lot of people: `position:relative` counterintuitively doesn't affect the DOM node you attach it to, it affects the absolute-positioned children of that node.  If a parent has `position:relative`, then any children with `position:absolute` will be placed relative to the parent's position instead of relative to the full window. If you're not using `position:absolute` (and you shouldn't unless absolutely necessary!) then you don't need `position:relative`.

Comment: You answer seems to be very universal, which is right up my alley. Really appreciate the in depth explanations. I guess, by trying to do such a "static" page layout I've overcomplicated things. Great stuff, once again thanks! ;)

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a box sizing problem.

Add this snippet to the top of your CSS (I always include it in my CSS reset), so that every element includes its children's padding and borders in its width/height:

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you don't want to apply it to everything, you can apply the styles instead to your `.main` and `.photo` classes.

As for your header, the content is overflowing because you have a set height, if you set the height to auto the header height adapts. However if you want to preserve the height of the header, you can change the **overflow** property to `overflow:hidden`,  which hides overlapping content; or `overflow:auto` which adds a scroll bar on overflow.